# Make fragment to a image file and save it to internal harddrive on the phone

Tags: android, android-bitmap, fileoutputstream

I want to make an fragment to png file and save it on the device. But i dont understand how to save the file to the device internal storage.I get the exception "FileNotFoundException e" when i try the program.

```
Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                View fragment = (View) findViewById(R.id.fragment2);
                viewToBitmap(fragment);
            }
        }
        );
    }

    public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        try {
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/to/file.png");

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
            output.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a FileOutputStream but you have not created a File before that. You need to create a FileFolder and a File before writing an output stream to that File. Corrected code below for your method `viewToBitmap`

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                view.draw(canvas);
                try {
                File tempFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/to");
                if (!tempFolder.exists()) tempFolder.mkdirs();
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("tempFile", ".jpg", tempFolder);
                        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
                        output.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }
```